# Problems setting up junit & mockito in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to setup my project for unit testing.

I tried to follow the instructions on [Android's page](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#setup):

```
// Unit testing dependencies
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
// Set this dependency if you want to use Hamcrest matching
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
```

However, when doing that and creating a test, I get:

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'junit'"
>
> "Cannot resolve symbol 'mockito'"

In [Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_android2), a lot more dependencies are required, and I want the bare minimum.

Also, using Vogel's tutorial, I get:

> Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (22.2.1) and test app (22.2.0) differ.

**So my question is:** How can I get the dependencies from Android's page to work?

Comment: Have you tried adding `testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1' ` explicitly?

Comment: Yap. does not help :/

Comment: I tried to answer some of your questions, but for the "Cannot resolve symbol 'junit'" errors, it's not clear when and how you get that. Just by trying to put the code in? Has gradle actually worked and put the dependencies in the project? Has gradle failed to build?

Comment: i am facing same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The support-annotations issue is a known one. You can find the info [in their issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=136). To workaround it, in the main (app, not module) build.gradle file, section allprojects add

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

(see answer [#11](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=136#c11) in the same link).

About the extra dependencies, you are going to need dexmaker and dexmaker-mockito for using mockito for your tests in devices/emulator, as they run on a Dalvik VM that expects .dex files, while mockito generates .class files. Unit testing as in the newest unit testing added to Android Studio, runs in your local JVM so it should probably run without dexmaker, but I cannot confirm this as of yet.